# Vidyo.io - No audio sent when using Firefox for Android

Tags: android, firefox, audio, webrtc, vidyo

Video calls fail to transmit audio from Firefox for Android (I have not changed anything on the code and everything worked just fine earlier. Firefox receives audio just fine). I have tried to test Webrtc separately (audio/video) and everything seems ok. The only thing I can come up is that the problem is within the Vidyo.io library or Firefox. I also tested this problem with Vidyo.io demo page and multiple devices. I get no errors from vidyo.io api. Other browsers work as expected (on Android). I have even tried to install earlier versions of Firefox and Vidyo.io with no success.

Comment: Btw. I'm using Firefox for Android 61 and Vidyo.io 4.1.22.9.

Answer (score 0):

Vidyo.io only supports Chrome on Android for now. However, we are working towards supporting other mobile browsers like Firefox and iOS Safari in the future.